# How to write custom Expressions

Tags: python-polars

I would like to use a custom expression within another expression like in this artificially simple example:

```py
import polars as pl


def expr1(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col('A').expr2(method).abs()

def expr2(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    if method == 'ceil':
        return pl.col('A').ceil()
    elif method == 'floor':
        return pl.col('A').floor()
    else:
        raise ValueError()


df = pl.Series('A', [0]).to_frame()

df.select(
    expr1('ceil')
)
```

Obviously this won't work as my custom function is not an attribute of an `Expr` object:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 18>()
     13         raise ValueError()
     16 df = pl.DataFrame(schema={'A': pl.Int32})
     18 df.select(
---> 19     expr1('ceil')
     20 )

Input In [4], in expr1(method)
      4 def expr1(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
----> 5     return pl.col('A').expr2(method).abs()

AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'expr2'
```

This is a very artificial example for simplicity, but the overall goal here is to be able to "call" a custom expression from within another expression. How can I do that?

Then I thought, that maybe chaining would work, but this also doesn't work for the same reason:

```py
import polars as pl


def expr1(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col('A').abs()

def expr2(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    if method == 'ceil':
        return pl.col('A').ceil()
    elif method == 'floor':
        return pl.col('A').floor()
    else:
        raise ValueError()


df = pl.Series('A', [0]).to_frame()

df.select(
    expr2('ceil').expr1()
)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 18>()
     13         raise ValueError()
     16 df = pl.DataFrame(schema={'A': pl.Int32})
     18 df.select(
---> 19     pl.col('A').expr2('ceil').expr1()
     20 )

AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'expr2'
```

I then tried to use `apply()` or `map()`, but this also does not work:

```py
import polars as pl


def expr1(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col('A').apply(expr2(method)).abs()

def expr2(method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    if method == 'ceil':
        return pl.col('A').ceil()
    elif method == 'floor':
        return pl.col('A').floor()
    else:
        raise ValueError()


df = pl.Series('A', [0]).to_frame()

df.select(
    expr1('ceil')
)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ComputeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 18>()
     13         raise ValueError()
     16 df = pl.Series('A', [0]).to_frame()
---> 18 df.select(
     19     expr1('ceil')
     20 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py:6445, in DataFrame.select(self, exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)
   6337 def select(
   6338     self,
   6339     exprs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr] | None = None,
   6340     *more_exprs: IntoExpr,
   6341     **named_exprs: IntoExpr,
   6342 ) -> Self:
   6343     """
   6344     Select columns from this DataFrame.
   6345 
   (...)
   6442 
   6443     """
   6444     return self._from_pydf(
-> 6445         self.lazy()
   6446         .select(exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)
   6447         .collect(no_optimization=True)
   6448         ._df
   6449     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py:1438, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, common_subplan_elimination, streaming)
   1427     common_subplan_elimination = False
   1429 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
   1430     type_coercion,
   1431     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
   1436     streaming,
   1437 )
-> 1438 return pli.wrap_df(ldf.collect())

ComputeError: TypeError: 'Expr' object is not callable
```

It seems to me that `apply()` and `map()` cannot be used with polars expressions but instead only with python functions.

Still, there must be a way to chain and nest custom expressions, right?

Comment: `expr2(method)` is `pl.col('A').ceil()` - so just `expr2(method).abs()` instead of `pl.col('A').expr2(method).abs()` ... if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are the docs to how to extend the API](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_expr_namespace.html)

If you don't want to make a new namespace you can monkey path your new Expressions into the `pl.Expr` namespace.

However your `expr1` and `expr2` aren't consistent. In `expr1` you're trying to invoke `expr2` from `pl.col('A')` but `expr2` doesn't refer to itself, it's hard coded to `col('A')`.

Assuming your intention is to make a "normal" expression that doesn't have embedded hard coded columns then you don't need two expressions you'd just do this:

```
def expr2(self, method: str) -> pl.Expr:
    if method == 'ceil':
        return self.ceil()
    elif method == 'floor':
        return self.floor()
    else:
        raise ValueError()
pl.Expr.expr2=expr2 #this is the monkey patching
del expr2 # not strictly necessary but it keeps the global cleaned up
```

Your other issue is that you can't do `ceil` against an int. So if you had started with something like

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'A':[1.1,2.2,3.3]})
```

then you could do

```
df.select(pl.col('A').expr2('ceil'))
```

and

```
df.select(pl.col("A").expr2('floor'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, registering expressions will be the way to go I think.

Comment: My example is very artificial such that is as simple as possible. You're totally right of course that using ceil on int datatypes does not make any sense. I just used it for demonstration purposes and forgot about the actual datatype.